# Retornar todos dados do primeiro ao último dia do mês com mysql

Tags: mysql

estou fazendo uma busca em uma tabela na minha base que precise que retorne todos os dados que foram criados no mês corrente (irei rodar um cron no último dia do mês às 23:00). Tenho na minha tabela um campo `created_at` que guarda o data inserida na base o registro.

O que fiz foi o seguinte:

```
SELECT *
FROM minha_tabela
WHERE created_at >= date_add(last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)), interval 1 day) 
AND created_at <= last_day(curdate());
```

Esta funcionando, só que gostaria de saber se é melhor eu deixar assim mesmo ou se tem alguma forma melhor para se fazer, pensando em performance e manutenção.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode só selecionar o mês e o ano, ao invés de selecionar por um intervalo de dias.

```
SELECT * FROM minha_tabela
WHERE MONTH(created_at)=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(created_at)=YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Dessa forma, você seleciona todos os registros no mês atual.

Comment: Uma forma que pelo menos já facilita na manutenção, e pelo que vi melhora nem piora a performance. Valew

Comment: Não posso dizer no mysql, mas no sql server existe uma perda de performance caso o campo utilize índices, pois eles são desconsiderados quando o `where` é calculado através de uma expressão (`month()` e `year()` nesse caso)

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo da forma que você explicou, você esta com uma janela de uma hora, e os registros criados nesse período nunca vão passar por este processo...

Sugiro que você crie a cronjob no primeiro minuto de todo dia primeiro do mês, e a query seleciona todos os registros do mês anterior:

```
SELECT *
FROM minha_tabela
WHERE YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e61c1/2)